# how can i limit count of duplicate rows in oracle?

Tags: oracle

`create table file( member_no  number, filepath varchar2(100) );`

I want to limit the number of duplicate rows of member_no in this table.
for example:

[image]

In this way, the number of member_no can be up to 5, but it shouldn't be more than six.
how can I do this?

Comment: Consider you have 4 times member_no = 1 and 2 times member_no = 2, what member_no should be assigned in this case?

Comment: Sorry, my question may have been incorrect.
The rows of member_no are unlimited.
However, the number of member_no=1 must be 5 or less.

Comment: Do you want to have member_no grouped in 5s or just not to have more than 5. Since you can wrap the insert with a procedure or make a trigger, which counts the occurrences of the member_no and changes it if with the new insert it will be more than 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two ways I can think of:

when you are inserting (i assume you are using a store procedure) run an if to check the current rows

```
Declare 
count number;
too_many_num_exception EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

select count(file_path) into count from file where member_no = <num_you_are_inserting>;

if(count = 5)
Then
    raise too_many_num_exception;
end if;

insert(...);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN too_many_num_exception then
        --do something

end;
```

or you could try play around with creating indexes on you tables (however this may not work - it's just a thought)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX file_ix1 on file (
CASE WHEN (select count() from file ... ) < 6 THEN member_id ELSE NULL END) 
online
```

Although im not 100% if that would work

Comment: wow really thank you! i used first one and it worked!