# how can i put a query in decode function?

Tags: spring, oracle

`create table ss( no  number, filepath varchar2(300) )`

I want to have 5 or less duplicate values of 'no' in this table

when `select count(no) from ss where no=#{no} <5`, `insert into ss values({no},{filepath})`

so duplicate values of 'no' can't be over 5.
how can i do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry. I'm trying to put a function to save pictures on the site. The site allows one member to store up to 5 photos. In the table above, 'no' is the member's unique number. For example, suppose that a user's unique number is 1. User 1 can only store up to 5 photos, so he can only occupy up to 5 photos in the no column.
Then column(no) will be 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5 like this. However, the number of 'no' rows must not exceed 5, such as 1,1,1,1,1,1.

Comment: Asking the same question over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286558/how-can-i-limit-count-of-duplicate-rows-in-oracle doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a similar trigger to implement this logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER set_no_ss_tbl_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON ss_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE
   l_cnt_no NUMBER;
  BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO l_exceeding
      FROM g_piece
     WHERE refdoss = :new.no;
    
    IF l_cnt_no > 5 THEN 

      SELECT MIN(no)
        INTO :new.no
        FROM (SELECT COUNT(1), no 
                FROM ss_tbl
               GROUP BY no 
              HAVING COUNT(1) + 1 <= 5);      
      
    END IF;
  END;
END;
```